# Change volume control increments/ticks?

Tags: settings, sound, indicator-sound

Is there any way to change the volume increment or ticks? With the default settings, the ticks are way too broad for my taste - one "tick" changes the volume by a large amount, I'd prefer finer control with each tick only increasing the volume by 1-2%. I found in Ubuntu 16.04 documentation for setting in dconf '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/sound/volume-step' but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Worse case scenario, I can create a custom mapping to change the volume using amixer, but I'd prefer to have the slick UI volume bubble pop-up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Has anyone answered this? I am also interested in a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where increasing the volume on my USB headset by one step (tick) would drastically increase the volume. Even worse, lowering the volume below a certain threshold (roughly 20-25%) would mute the sound alltogether.

I worked around this by installing pavucontrol (`sudo apt install pavucontrol`) and lowering the volume bar for my music application on the first tab.